# ReactJS POST a textvalue to an API

Tags: reactjs, api

I want to POST a value to a nodejs API.
So, user will input a value in textbox. I want to take that value and post it to  a nodejs api.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from "react";

import './App.css';
import logo from './logo.svg';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Info: '' };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    alert('A form was submitted: ' + this.state);

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/', {
        
        // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        method: 'POST',
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      });

    event.preventDefault();
}







  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This code is not working for me . No value is getting inserted to database.

POST variable is **"Info"**

Comment: Try to use header : application/json.

Is handleSubmit called once you hit input Submit?

Answer (score 1):

The input name must match the state name you choosed `Info`

```js
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="Info" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

because you choosed to update the state using `Computed property names`

```js
this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
```

or you can just write it explicity like

```js
this.setState({ Info: event.target.value });
```

and to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body type you have to provide the body with `URLSearchParams` or `FormData`

```js
var body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append('Info', this.state.Info);

....

fetch( url, { ...., body: body } )
```